# What is the English equivalent of a vulgar expression for continuous nagging?

Tags: expressions, offensive-language

In more than one language I know, when someone keeps nagging about a  subject that you do not want to hear about but you have to because that person is your boss or your wife and their talking goes on and on until they cause damage to your brain, one says something that literally translates to *they fucked my brain*.

- in Arabic " ناك راسي يازلمة"
- [in Russian "ебать мозги"](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B3%D0%B8)

I know *hit my nerve* but that doesn't convey to what extent the damage is done to the brain, do you have anything much stronger?

[another reference](http://www.russki-mat.net/page.php?l=RuEn&a=%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B3%D0%B8)

Comment: 'motor mouth, ear basher, GBH of the ear, talk the leg off a table' are some expressions I have come across.

Comment: "You're breaking my balls"

Comment: "Quit busting my chops", "You're a real ball buster"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the closest fit, albeit not as vulgar, is:

*They chewed my ear off.*

Comment: Welcome to EL&U Stack Exchange. If you added a source (ideally etymological/literary) for this phrase it would make your answer even better.

Comment: Would it make sense to you if we say "Chewed my brain off" ?

Comment: @Sam: There is an entry for "chew someone's ear off" on [dictionary.reference.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/chew+someone's+ear+off). It, in turn, cites _The Dictionary of American Slang_, Fourth Edition, by Kipfer and Chapman.

Comment: @Mike: not sure whether this would be widely understood, unless you provided some context.

Answer (score 2):

A harpy according to Dictionary.com is

1. a ravenous, filthy monster having a woman's head and a bird's body.
2. (lowercase) a scolding, nagging, bad-tempered woman; shrew.

So for example, you could say, 'I wish my wife would quit harping on me to take the trash out.'

Answer (score 2):

**Carping** is a possibility, although it doesn't have the nuance of "brain damage via nagging".

From m-w.com: "Marked by or inclined to querulous and often perverse criticism."

Answer (score 1):

Here are some ideas:

- *They got on my nerves.*  (You're right, this is not very strong.)
- *They drove me up the wall, drove me nuts, drove me up the wall, drove me crazy, drove me mad, drove me berserk.*
- *He kept at me until I was ready to wring his neck.*
- *They made my life a living hell.* (My favorite)

Answer (score 1):

To **do someone's head in** (*British informal*)

Defined under [head](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/head), phrases (defn. 10) as:

make someone feel annoyed, confused or frustrated

> '*My relationship with my publicist was doing my head in.*'

Source: ODO

Answer (score 1):

**My brains are dribbling out my ears** is sometimes used when too much information is producing boredom and lack of focus. It's somewhat more general in meaning as it applies to *any* source of information, not just being spoken to, but it does have the advantage of implying brain damage like your non-English examples.

[A Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=brains%20dribbling%20out%20my%20ears&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) turns up quite a few examples of its use, primarily in pop culture like SF novels and an episode of "Buffy the Vampire Slayer".